# SCSS styling not applying as expected

Tags: .net, sass

I have the following bootstrap dropdown list I am building

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle option-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@Model.SelectedOption <span style="border-right:2px solid #68D0ED;margin-right:8px; margin-left:5px"></span><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @foreach (var option in Model.Options)
        {
            <li><a class="option" href='@string.Format("/controller?option={0}", option )'>@option</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

and am trying to apply the following styles based on class names `option-dropdown` and `option`. My styles apply as expected when using inline css styles however when I move these to a `.scss` file, the styles no longer apply. I am not sure where I'm going wrong as I'm somewhat new to sass. My understanding (which is apparently incorrect) was that I could still select off of class names to apply styles the same way I would in css. All help is appreciated. My sass file is below:

```
.option {
    color: #68D0ED;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.option-dropdown {
    border: 2px solid #68D0ED;
    color: #68D0ED;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether your file is being executing in the browser or not by Inspect (Ctrl+Shift+i) and then go to sources. Check there in sources whether your .css file is present there or not. Clear the cache memory.

Comment: please see my comment in response to @Federico

Comment: Sorry. Then please check whether your file is being executing in the browser or not by Inspect (Ctrl+Shift+i) and then go to sources. Check there in sources whether your  .css file is present there or not.

Comment: This led me to finding the issue. After years as a web dev I can't believe I just let this bite me again. Needed to clear cache... sigh. Go ahead and update your question and I'll accept it.

Comment: :)
This also bite me several times :D